# SQL issue ORA-02438 not able to create a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Error:

> ORA-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns
> 02438. 00000 -  "Column check constraint cannot reference other columns"
> Cause:    attempted to define a column check constraint that references another column.
> Action:   define it as a table check constraint.

```sql
CREATE TABLE crime_charges 
(
    charge_id number(10) CONSTRAINT crime_charges_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    crime_id number(9) CONSTRAINT crime_charges_crime_id_fk
                       REFERENCES crimes(crime_id),
    crime_code number(3) CONSTRAINT crime_charges_crime_code_fk
                         REFERENCES crime_codes (crime_code),
    charge_status varchar2(2),
    fine_amount number(2),
    court_fee number(7),
    amount_paid number(7),
    pay_due_date date
    CONSTRAINT charge_status_CHECK
        CHECK (charge_status IN ('PD','GL', 'NG'))
);
```

Is not letting me create the table, I am trying to find the solution but nothing comes up

Comment: You are missing a `,` comma after `pay_due_date date` and before the final constraint. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cO2flfXc)

Answer (score 1):

It is about a **missing comma** or **misplaced constraint clause**. Because, the way you put it, Oracle *thinks* you're creating check constraint on `pay_due_date` column and it (Oracle) won't let you do that as column check constraint can't reference another columns.

However, if you put it onto a table level (1st example) or appropriate column (2nd example), then it works as expected.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE crime_charges (
  2      charge_id     NUMBER(10)
  3          CONSTRAINT crime_charges_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  4      crime_id      NUMBER(9)
  5          CONSTRAINT crime_charges_crime_id_fk
  6              REFERENCES crimes ( crime_id ),
  7      crime_code    NUMBER(3)
  8          CONSTRAINT crime_charges_crime_code_fk
  9              REFERENCES crime_codes ( crime_code ),
 10      charge_status VARCHAR2(2),
 11      fine_amount   NUMBER(2),
 12      court_fee     NUMBER(7),
 13      amount_paid   NUMBER(7),
 14      pay_due_date  DATE,
 15      --
 16      CONSTRAINT charge_status_check CHECK ( charge_status IN ( 'PD', 'GL', 'NG' ) )
 17  );

Table created.
```

---

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE crime_charges (
  2      charge_id     NUMBER(10)
  3          CONSTRAINT crime_charges_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  4      crime_id      NUMBER(9)
  5          CONSTRAINT crime_charges_crime_id_fk
  6              REFERENCES crimes ( crime_id ),
  7      crime_code    NUMBER(3)
  8          CONSTRAINT crime_charges_crime_code_fk
  9              REFERENCES crime_codes ( crime_code ),
 10      charge_status VARCHAR2(2)
 11      CONSTRAINT charge_status_check CHECK ( charge_status IN ( 'PD', 'GL', 'NG' ) ),
 12      fine_amount   NUMBER(2),
 13      court_fee     NUMBER(7),
 14      amount_paid   NUMBER(7),
 15      pay_due_date  DATE
 16  );

Table created.
```